# Изменяю файл на сервере по ftp, обновляю страницу - изменений нет. Кто кэширует?

Tags: кэширование, windows-10

Изменяю файл на сервере по `ftp`, обновляю страницу - изменений нет.
Захожу в панель на сервере, смотрю файл - изменения в файле есть (значит не `ftp`).
Открываю другой браузер - тоже самое (хотя я им никогда не пользовался).
С ноута работает и с одного модема.
Это проблема появляется при частом обновлении одной и той же страницы (F5).

Кэш браузера чистил, DNS винды - тоже. Куда еще копать?

Comment: А где в вашей проблеме роль Windows 10? У неё, насколько я понимаю, нет встроенного ftp-сервера.

Comment: Вы не допускаете, что проблема на стороне сервера, который не подхватывает залитые по ftp изменения?

Comment: @VladD я думаю тут даже не важно чем я пользуюсь, так как файл на сервере изменяется. Залил я измененный по FTP и для уверенности зашел в ispmanager и проверил. Дело именно в винде, где именно понять не могу.

Comment: А какой стороной, ещё раз, Windows участвует в проблеме? Она не разрешает серверу увидеть обновлённый файл? Она заставляет браузер не слать запрос на сервер? Она при выводе браузером контента на экран хитро подменяет его на старый контент? Опишите сценарий, который вы себе представляете.

Comment: @VladD Это: Она при выводе браузером контента на экран хитро подменяет его на старый контент. И причем в любом браузере. Но спустя минут 5 - 10 обновляет с сервера. А потом опять история повторяется.

Comment: Какая подлая Windows! И не говорите.

Comment: @VladD а я серьезно! Вот попадете как я, вспомните.

Comment: И я серьёзно. Не может Windows кешировать вывод за браузер, невозможно это, да и какой смысл, абстрактная подлость? Вы лучше запустите dev tools в браузере и посмотрите на коммуникацию с сервером. Вангую, что сервер тупо не подхватил обновлённый контент. Или что он отправляет заголовок `Expires` длиной в те самые 5 минут.

Comment: @VladD хороший вопрос, вот тут я 0 :))) http://f3.s.qip.ru/12ssF4Tjx.png

Comment: В моей схожей проблеме следующие «танцы с бубном» помогают: // 1) Обновляю страницу через Ctrl+F5, а не F5. // 2) Открываю страницы не своего домена 2-го уровня, а домена 3-го уровня, предоставленного хостингом. // 3) Нужный URL в адресную строку вбиваю вручную. // 4) Перехожу на другую страницу моего сайта, в которой последним действием не было проведено изменений, затем возвращаюсь на изменённую. Опять же не через кнопку «назад», а вводя адрес вручную. // 5) Открываю панель управления, проверяю, внесены ли изменения. Удостоверившись, вписываю URL в адресную строку. // Спасибо.

Comment: @wwwplaton: Ну так посмотрите заодно, какой контент приходит. Старый или новый.

Comment: Все это я пробовал. И ставил мозилу на чистую, не было ее у меня. На чистенькую зашел. И он мне выдал старое, а не новое изменение. А что самое интересное, если вызвать ошибку в php то не кэширует! Я изменяю файл, просто провоцирую ошибку на разных строках что б понять кэширет или нет. Как только убрал ошибку, и загрузился html все. Курю.

Comment: Ребята, nginx? Или я рак?

Answer (score 1):

В Windows нет http-кэша для Firefox, Firefox сам внутри анализирует http.
В инструментах разработчика/сеть посмотрите список файлов, если статус 304, значит файл взят из кэша, если статус 200, значит браузер тянет файл по сети.
Дополнительно можно проанализировать трафик в Fiddler, Network Monitor, Wireshark. Логика везде одна - если браузер тянет файл по сети, то его и покажет, а не копию из кэша.
DNS и DNS-кэш влияют только на доступность всего сайта, но не отдельных файлов.
Проблема в настройках сервера или в прокси (тоже кэш).